Как корректно реализовать обводку текста?
Как корректно реализовать обводку текста, так как я добавил свойства -webkit-text-stroke-color;  -webkit-text-stroke-width, -webkit-text-fill-color, но у меня начал пропадать сам текст.
На данный момент как выглядит: 
Должно выглядеть: 


.container {
  max-width: 1726px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.hero {
  padding: 89px 0 112px 0;
  background-color: #f9d7bc;
}

.hero__wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-end;
  position: relative;
  gap: 32px;
}

.hero__title {
  font-size: 136px;
  line-height: 100%;
  /* 122.4px */
  letter-spacing: 1.36px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  max-width: 905px;
  width: 100%;
}

.hero__title-subtext {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 199px;
  display: block;
  font-family: var(--third-family);
  font-size: 136px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 100%;
  letter-spacing: unset;
  text-transform: none;
  color: #563419;
  -webkit-text-stroke-color: #F9D7BC;
  -webkit-text-stroke-width: 3px;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: #563419;
}

.hero__content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  gap: 58px;
  flex-basis: 618px;
}

.hero__text {
  font-family: var(--second-family);
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 124%;
}

.hero__button {
  max-width: 158px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #563419;
  padding: 30px 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: var(--font-main);
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 100%;
  /* 32px */
  letter-spacing: 0.32px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #f9d7bc;
}
<section class="hero">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="hero__wrapper">
      <h1 class="hero__title">
        best entertainment
        <span class="hero__title-subtext">Unlimite fun</span> center in Westfield
      </h1>
      <div class="hero__content">
        <p class="hero__text">
          A space for everyone: for babies and for detached teenagers, for a gamer dad or a mom who loves drive , for a grandmoth who misses vivid emotions.
        </p>
        <button class="hero__button">Book now</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>




Буквально пару дней назад как раз с этим бодались.
можно опустить обводку с помощью свойства paint-order: stroke fill;
p.s. при слишком жирной обводке, как минимум в хроме результат может оказаться сомнительным. потому при столкновении с ощутимо бОльшей толщиной в т.з. рекомендую рассмотреть альтернативы из соседних ответов(там же).


.container {
  max-width: 1726px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.hero {
  padding: 89px 0 112px 0;
  background-color: #f9d7bc;
}

.hero__wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-end;
  position: relative;
  gap: 32px;
}

.hero__title {
  font-size: 136px;
  line-height: 100%;
  /* 122.4px */
  letter-spacing: 1.36px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  max-width: 905px;
  width: 100%;
}

.hero__title-subtext {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 199px;
  display: block;
  font-family: var(--third-family);
  font-size: 136px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 100%;
  letter-spacing: unset;
  text-transform: none;
  color: #563419;
  -webkit-text-stroke-color: #F9D7BC;
  -webkit-text-stroke-width: 3px;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: #563419;
  paint-order: stroke fill;                /*!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!*/
}

.hero__content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  gap: 58px;
  flex-basis: 618px;
}

.hero__text {
  font-family: var(--second-family);
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 124%;
}

.hero__button {
  max-width: 158px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #563419;
  padding: 30px 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-family: var(--font-main);
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 100%;
  /* 32px */
  letter-spacing: 0.32px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #f9d7bc;
}
<section class="hero">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="hero__wrapper">
      <h1 class="hero__title">
        best entertainment
        <span class="hero__title-subtext">Unlimite fun</span> center in Westfield
      </h1>
      <div class="hero__content">
        <p class="hero__text">
          A space for everyone: for babies and for detached teenagers,
          for a gamer dad or a mom who loves drive , 
          for a grandmoth who misses vivid emotions.
        </p>
        <button class="hero__button">Book now</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>




тооочно, я все искала, искала дубликат не нашла, помню, что видела похожее буквально на днях, но тут немного отличается(?), решила, пусть тоже будет ответ

@Dev18, там задача отличается -webkit-text-stroke. для той оказался неприемлим(в комментах скидывали скриншот результата....)
